# Injected script from chrome extension returning values multiple times

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am writing an chrome extension to tracks user's whats app activity (weather he/she is online or offline) by injecting a script into DOM but I am getting multiple entries for same numbers in my firebase when I run it and it runs only for one time even though I have written line to inject script after every 6 sec. here are my files please have a look

content.js

```js
var nos ;

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function gotnumbers(data){
 nos = data; 
    console.log(nos);
 setInterval( injectJs() , 5000);
});

function injectJs() {
        var scr = document.createElement("script");
        scr.type= "text/javascript";
        scr.id = 
        scr.textContent = load() ; 
        console.log(scr);
        (document.head).appendChild(scr);  
 }

document.addEventListener('hello' , passing, false);
function passing(e){
 chrome.runtime.sendMessage(e.detail);
}


//code////////////////////////////////////////////////
function load(){
 var actualCode = '(' +  function(nos,randoms) { 
 console.log(nos + " injected");
    'use strict';  
 nos.forEach(async (item,index) => {
        var s = false;
  Store.Presence.find( item + '@c.us').then(function(d){
            if (d.isOnline){
                s = true ;
            }
    
            var event = new CustomEvent('hello', { 'detail' : { 'number' : item , 'status' : s , 'time' : Date.now()}});
            document.dispatchEvent(event);
        });
 });
} + '(' + JSON.stringify(nos) + ',' + Math.random() + '));' ; 
return actualCode;
//code//////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

untitled.js(background.js)

```js
var REF =  firebase.database().ref();
var array ;
var flag = 1 ;

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
 chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib, {
  file: 'content.js'
 });
 address = tab.id;
 REF.child('numbers').once('value').then( function(snapshot){
 array = snapshot.val() ;
 console.log("number add/remove in firebase"); 
 console.log(array);
 chrome.tabs.sendMessage(address,array);
 });
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(data,sender){
  REF.child(data.number).push(data);
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: You're re-injecting the content script in onClicked so it registers a **new instance** of the listener function in chrome.runtime.onMessage so each instance receives the message you've sent from the background page. You can set `window.initDone` to `true` inside the content script and check it to avoid re-registering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As wOxxOm said in comment,

You are also injecting the content script in `onClicked` which results in registering a new instance of the listener function in `chrome.runtime`. so all instances receives the messages sent from the background page to content script.

Set `window.initDone` to true inside the content script and check it to avoid re-registering.